# Apache Tomcat: multiple webapps

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I'm developing a webapp using Apache Tomcat. This webapp will be deployed in a server which hosts other webapps. Now, since my webapp requires the user to authenticate, I'd need to modify some files in the "conf" directory of Tomcat such as "tomcat-users.xml". The problem is that these files are shared with the other webapps. Is there a way to have a "conf" directory for my webapp which is separated from the shared one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat allows you to [separate out](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) configuration from the main `server.xml` by creating an xml file underneath `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]` called `[YourWebappName].xml`.

For example: `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/PetClinic.xml`

This file bascially contains a `<Context>` element defining the webapp specific context configuration. In here you can define your own webapp specific [realm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Nested_Components) with the necessary authentication parameters for your app.

This mechanism is designed so that you can modify webapp specific configuration without touching the top-level shared files in Tomcat's `conf` folder.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have decided to define the context of my webapp creating a file called "context.xml" in the META-INF directory of my webapp. Now the problem is: what am I supposed to write in that .xml file? I'd know how to modify the "tomcat-users.xml" and the "server.xml" files in Tomcat's "conf" folder to implement authentication but I really don't know how to translate those changes in the context.xml file. Can you help me?

Comment: You can nest a `Realm` element directly underneath the `Context` element in your `context.xml` file (you should be able to pretty much lift it wholesale from your `server.xml`). You can also create a `WEB-INF/users.xml` file for the webapp specific users so you don't need to touch `tomcat-users.xml`. There's a good article [here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/SecuringYourSiteWithContainerManagedSecurity) (albeit a few years old - but should still be good) that walks you through it with examples of what the files should look like.

Comment: You don't need to create a `conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[YourWebappName].xml.` You can provide a META-INF/Context.xml inside your webapp.