# Deploy multiple webapps with application specific config in Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I have a Tomcat 7 Server in Eclipse with two webapps ***a*** and ***b*** and need to find out how to have application specific configuration files for tomcat that works with Eclipse.

Now I want for each webapp a custom config file, like described here: [Apache Tomcat: multiple webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514817/apache-tomcat-multiple-webapps). So I created a `<TomcatDirectory>/conf/Catalina/localhost` folder and put the `a.xml` and `b.xml` there. This works fine when I run Tomcat from command line.

But **where have I to put the application specific configuration files `a.xml` and `b.xml` when I run Tomcat from within eclipse?**

*I already tried to put the files in Eclipse in `<EclipseWorkspace>\Servers\<ServerName>\conf\Catalina\localhost\` but WTP does not copy this files to `<EclipseWorkspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost`*

Comment: Why not to put this file into the appropriate webapp project?

Comment: The files are located in the server, because they contain server specific configurations like database connection and passwords. (Because this configurations differ from server to server, one can not put them in the application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave them in `<TomcatDirectory>/conf/Catalina/localhost`

Server > Open > Server Locations

Change from:
*Use workspace metadata*
To:
*Use Tomcat instalation*

Now **a.xml** and **b.xml** from `<TomcatDirectory>/conf/Catalina/localhost` will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works quite good, but i have the problem that on redeploy it resets my config files to the default ones.

Comment: My guess is, on redeploy it takes files(context.xml etc.) from <EclipseWorkspace>\Servers\<ServerName>. Update them.

Comment: The context.xml only contains `<Context><WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource></Context>`. But it replaces my two config files for example with `<Context docBase="<docBasePath>" path="/a">`, so the contexts for the single webapps. If i don't add the webapps in eclipse, it just deletes my configs on publish.

Comment: What context.xml you have in <EclipseWorkspace>\Servers\<ServerName>? When you start server on eclipse, it will take config files <EclipseWorkspace>\Servers\<ServerName> and will write them on <TomcatDirectory>/conf

Answer (score 1):

If it's for development's purpose, you can specify a folder into the "docBase" attribute of context file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context crossContext="true" docBase="C:/devel/MyApp/web/target/MyApp-web" path="/MyApp" reloadable="true">
    <Resource
        ... />
</Context>
```

By adding these context files directly into /conf/Catalina/localhost, everything is configured and should work like you want but you'll have to stop the tomcat server every time you'll want to clean and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to have context.xml files for two different applications.create context.xml file under web application's (a and b) META-INF folder and you should be able to run both the application with their own context.xml file. In eclipse you should be able to create META-INF folder for your respective web applications in parallel to WEB-INF directory

Comment: The context files can't be put in the application, because they are not the same for all servers -- that is why they are located in the server.

Comment: I think David has mentioned specific server,Tomcat, and context.xml works fine in Tomcat.

Comment: application specific config files located in <TomcatDirectory>/conf/Catalina/localhost (with an link to an question/answer that describe this technique) -- I do not know how to express it better - do you have an idea? - btw. David is my college and I recommended him to post his question at stack overflow